# how to save multiple file upload path to database in laravel?

Tags: file, upload, laravel-5

I wanted to upload multiple files in the public folder and multiple file path in the database, i am able to upload multiple files in the public folder but i am not able to save multiple file path in db. only one file name and path gets stored in the database.

in the View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-border" action="<?= URL::to('/checkiou') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple/> 
<input name="save" type="submit" value="Save">
```

in the controller

```
public function upload() {

        // Request the file input named 'attachments'

   // Request the file input named 'attachments'
      $files = Request::file('attachments');

      //If the array is not empty
      if ($files[0] != '') {
        foreach($files as $file) {
     // Set the destination path
        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
     // Get the orginal filname or create the filename of your choice
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     // Copy the file in our upload folder
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
   }

 $data1 = DB::table('tbl_iou')->max('iou_id');
        $check=0;
        $check=DB::table('tbl_iou')
                ->where('iou_id',$data1)
             ->update(array('image_path'=>$destinationPath,   'file_name'=>$filename));

       if ($check > 0)
       {
          $_SESSION['msg']="Petty cash details saved Successfully";
          return Redirect::to('iou_accounts');
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you execute second part of code, where you want to insert data to database, outside of foreach loop. So you update only once for last file.

Secondly, your `$data1` variable store only maximal (assume last) `iou_id` from `tbl_iou` table. And in code:

```
$check=DB::table('tbl_iou')
    ->where('iou_id',$data1)
    ->update(array(
         'image_path'=>$destinationPath,
         'file_name'=>$filename
    ));
```

you search for row where this `iou_id` is equeal to the last, so you update values for the only one row, with the maximal `iou_id` in table.

I suggest following way to solve this. I assume that in your database table your have autogenerated `iou_id` and you only insert new rows, not update.

```
public function upload() {
        // Request the file input named 'attachments'

        // Request the file input named 'attachments'
        $files = Request::file('attachments');
        //If the array is not empty
        if (!empty($files[0])) {
            $filesData = array();
            foreach($files as $file) {
                // Set the destination path
                $destinationPath = 'testuploads';
                // Get the orginal filname or create the filename of your choice
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                // Copy the file in our upload folder
                $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

                // ADD DATA TO TEMPORARY ARRAY
                $filesData[] = array('image_path'=>$destinationPath,   'file_name'=>$filename);
            }

            if(DB::table('tbl_iou')->insert($filesData)){
                $_SESSION['msg']="Petty cash details saved Successfully";
                return Redirect::to('iou_accounts');
            }
        }
    }
```